# how to train Large Dataset on free gpu in Google Colab if the stated training time is more than 12 hours?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, dataset, gpu, google-colaboratory

If my dataset is large say 15000 images and i am using gpu and the ETA which it shows for training is almost 15 hours but the limit for free gpu is 12 hours, Can you suggest what shall be done to train it??

Comment: Consider adding tags to this question. It will help users find your question much easier

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I would like to suggest you add that you are training in **Google Colab** in the text body. I had to parse that information from the question tags.

---

Now coming back to your question. It is possible to train for 15 hours on Colab, but it's not straight forward. Also, the 12 hours limit you mentioned is for *active usage* meaning you need to be actively interacting with the notebook. If your notebook is idle for more than 90 minutes Colab will terminate your connection.

So the easy workaround for this would be to modify your code such that you save model checkpoints periodically to your Google drive. Keep making changes in the notebook once in a while so that your notebook is *active*. Even if your session is terminated, you can easily restore the checkpoint from your Google drive and resume training.

Connect Colab to your drive by

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

---

On a side note, 15000 images is not that large. I am not aware of your model architecture, but typically this amount of data should be processed without consuming much time. If you feel that the above method is not suitable for you, you can try out with cloud providers such as AWS, GCP or Azure.

Comment: Thankyou for the comment. I did save the checkpoints and was able to train my model.